# Reading .data file in r

Tags: r, dataset

I need to read a data file of type .data(can be found [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Ionosphere)). I have never seen nor read a file like this before and when I try to read.table(file = "ionosphere.data") all of the attributes for a single instance are all grouped together. How do I properly read this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to specify the separator in `read.table`: `read.table("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/ionosphere/ionosphere.data", sep = ",")`

Answer (score 0):

It's a UTF-16  file with a byte order mark at the beginning. read.table will fail unless you specify the correct encoding. This works for me on MacOS. Decimals are indicated by a comma.

```
read.table("ionosphere.data", fileEncoding="UTF-16", dec=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the file and type `x<-read.csv("D:/filedestination/ionosphere.data",header=F)` to view the data `view(ionosphere.data)`